# Navigating to module control using EditUrl does not load module control

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have a problem that appeared after it was working successfully for days.
I am running DNN 7.2.2 locally under dnndev.me.

I have a module with a main public view.  In that view I define the NavigateUrl for three hyperlinks to target different module controls.

here is how i declare the hyperlink urls:

```
 AddProductLink.NavigateUrl = EditUrl("AddProduct")
 ManageOrdersLink.NavigateUrl = EditUrl("OrdersManagement")
 ManageStoreLink.NavigateUrl = EditUrl("StoreManagement")
```

The **AddProductLink** and **ManageOrdersLink** work perfectly, and the **ManageStoreLink** has been working for days wihtout trouble.

Now, all of a sudden, the **ManageStoreLink** is no longer working.  The ManageStore Module control is an ascx usercontrol.

## What happens:

When I click the hyperlink for the **ManageStoreLink**, the **page_load** event of this usercontrol is called and executes without error, but then the home page of the website is loaded (http://www.dnndev.me) instead of the module control url (http://www.dnndev.me/ModuleDevelopment/KrisisStore/tabid/1106/ctl/StoreManagement/mid/2601/Default.aspx).

## Question

How can I figure out why the module control is not showing **OR** why it redirect to the home page after the module control loads?

There are no errors generated in the event viewer and I can debug and step through the page_load events (which happen in this order) of the StoreManagement.ascx, login.ascx, user.ascx, and default.aspx and I do not see any redirects getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

after totally re-writing my user control I realised that one of the asp:requiredfieldvalidators was referencing a textbox that did not exist.  Once I fixed this, the problem went away.

The frustrating thing is that there was no error shown and no error created in the event log.  It took quite a while to narrow this down.